# Why is this Date().description not working?

Tags: swift, swift3

Is this valid swift code? If it is why does it produce an error?

```
import Foundation
Date().description
Date().description
```

Comment: what error are you having?

Comment: @FelipeSabino http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58004ebcd84ec5570488046a This error occurs on my local machine not just ibm's

Answer (score 2):

Try using it like:

```
let date = Date().description
print(date)
```

Output:

```
2016-10-14 04:02:48 +0000
```

Example:

http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5800590a81fd55031921c321

Comment: This is not supposed to be code in use. I am wondering why I can not create two instances of Date().

Comment: that I call .description on

Comment: First explain what you are trying to do; currently you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: I am simply trying to get the date in as string twice in the same script